# How to make pd.to_datetime insert last day of month instead of first when input is limited to 'yyyy-mm'?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a pandas dataframe with a timeseries of the form:

```
Date  value
2020-01  1
2020-02  2
2020-03  3
```

I'd like to efficiently make this into a datetime series using for example [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

This can easily be done like below ***if*** you'd like the inserted day part of the date to be **`01`**

**code:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: '2020-01', 1: '2020-02', 2: '2020-03'},
                  'value': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}})
df['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df
```

**output:**

```
      date  value   datetime
0  2020-01      1 2020-01-01
1  2020-02      2 2020-02-01
2  2020-03      3 2020-03-01
```

As you can see, it's assumed that the preferred day of month is the first day of the month. But how can you make sure that you get the last day of the month instead?

**desired output:**

```
      date  value   datetime
0  2020-01      1 2020-01-31
1  2020-02      2 2020-02-28
2  2020-03      3 2020-03-31
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think not possible in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), possible solution is add values after converting to datetimes:

```
df['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()
print (df)
      date  value   datetime
0  2020-01      1 2020-01-31
1  2020-02      2 2020-02-29
2  2020-03      3 2020-03-31
```

Comment: Very elegant and exactly what I was l looking for. Thank you!

Comment: I have a small follow-up question. I've tried looking at the formula documentation, but could not understand how `pd.offsets.MonthEnd()` knows which month it finds the end to. Maybe I'm missing something very obvious here, but could you briefly explain the inner workings of this?

Comment: @vestland - sure, if check [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects) - `The basic DateOffset acts similar to dateutil.relativedelta (relativedelta documentation) that shifts a date time by the corresponding calendar duration specified.`

Comment: @vestland - so it means in my opinion it check dates and add last end day to them, but how exactly internal working not idea, because not pandas developer

Comment: Thank you again for yet another valuable pandas answer!

Answer (score 1):

Build appropriate string first, then convert

```
import calendar
get_last_day = lambda x: calendar.monthrange(*map(int, x.split('-')))[1]
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date.apply(lambda x: '{}-{}'.format(x, get_last_day(x))))
```